# android studio, permisos de geolocalización

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

estoy intentando ejecutar permisos  de geolocalización desde un fragment y a su vez ejecutar dos acciones distintas en caso de aceptar o rechazar dicho permiso.

Explicado de otro modo sería.

si el usuario **acepta** los permisos de geolocalización ingresa a **locationStar()** gestiona todo para tomar los puntos de latitud y longitud del despositivo móvil y luego llamo a un link en donde le anexo dicha latitud y longitud, ejemplo. www.buscarenlaciudad.com/**latitud&longitud**

Pero en caso de que el usuario **rechace** dicho permiso solo tengo que ir a cargarwebview y le paso la latitud y la longitud con valores 0.0 para armar el link www.buscarenlaciudad.com/.

Hasta ahora esto es lo que intente hacer pero no me funciona, pero no se si esta bien usar el requestPermissions .

```
public class YavieneFragment extends Fragment {
 // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

 // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
//LocationManager locationManager;
double longitud, latitud = 0.0;
boolean Primeraubicacion = true;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
WebView webView;

ImageView imageView;
 private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
 private int duracion_splash = 2300;
 private Timer timer;
 private ProgressBar progressBar;
 private int i = 0;
 Toast toast;

  private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 
  10 metros
  private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 
  minuto
  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  public YavieneFragment() {
  // Required empty public constructor

  }
  // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  double longitud = 0.0 ; latitud = 0.0;
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if (getArguments() != null) {
    mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
    mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

}

if (checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            99);
}


}

                                                                                                private void locationStart() {
    Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a locationStar");
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) 
   requireContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
Local.setMainActivity(this);
assert mlocManager != null;
final boolean gpsEnabled = 
  mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

  if (!gpsEnabled) {
    Intent settingsIntent = new 
 Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
    Log.e("titulo","ingresa a !gpsEnabled");
}




if (checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(getActivity(),
            new String[] 
    {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            99);
       return;
    } else{
    Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED");
    }

toast = Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext(),
        "Por favor aguarde, ésto puede demorar unos segundos...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(requireContext());
progressDialog.show();
progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
Objects.requireNonNull(progressDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, (LocationListener) Local);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,(LocationListener) Local);
   }

 private void requestPermissions(FragmentActivity activity,String[] 
    strings,int i) {

    Log.e("titulo","ingresa a RequestPermissionsResult");
           if (requestCode == 99) {

              if (grantResults[0] == 
             PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   locationStart();
                   return;
               }else
               {
                    Cargarwebview(0.0, 0.0);
               }
           }
     }

     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull 
    String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {




    }
    //LLAMA AL SERVIDOR PARA CARGAR EL WEB VIEW
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void Cargarwebview(double latitud,double longitud) throws 
    MalformedURLException {
    Log.e("titulo","ingresa a CargarWebView");
    final WebView webView = 



 Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.yaviene_webview);
   ImageView imagen = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.imagen_principal);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.reload();
toast = Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext(),
        "Su consulta está terminado de ser procesada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
webView.loadUrl("http://www.buscarenlaciudad.com/index.php?a="+getString(R.string.NumeroE)+"&v=1&lat="+latitud+"&Lng="+longitud);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erroryaviene.html");
        } });


progressDialog.dismiss();
imagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}


     public void setLocation(Location loc) {
//Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
       // List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
        List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1); //ESTO TRAE LA DIRECCIÓN CON ALTURA, CALLE, LOCALIDAD, PAIS
    /*  if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
            mensaje2.setText("Mi direccion es: \n"
                    + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
        }*/
        Log.e("titulo","Esto trae Geocoder"+ list);
        Log.e("titulo","Esta es la latitud: "+ loc.getLatitude()+" y esta es tu longitud "+loc.getLongitude());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}



/* Aqui empieza la Clase Localizacion */
    public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
      YavieneFragment mainActivity;

      // YavieneFragment CheckIn;

public YavieneFragment getMainActivity() {
    return mainActivity;
}

/*public void setMainActivity( com.example.christian.guatemayaapp.CheckIn mainActivity) {
    this.CheckIn = CheckIn;
}*/


void setMainActivity(matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctest.YavieneFragment mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a localizacion setMainActivity ");
    toast = Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext(),
            "Procesando su ubicación actual", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}



@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que el GPS recibe nuevas coordenadas
    Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a localizacion onLocationChanged ");
    // debido a la deteccion de un cambio de ubicacion
    latitud= loc.getLatitude();
    Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae latitud ->"+latitud);
    longitud = loc.getLongitude();
    Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae longitud ->"+longitud);

    //CONSULTA SI ES LA PRIMERA UBICACION QUE TOMA EL GPS AL PRESIONAL EL BOTON YA VIENE Y LA ENVÍA, CASO CONTRARIO NO INGRESA
    if (Primeraubicacion){

        try {
            //CargarMapaGPS(latitud,longitud);
            Cargarwebview(latitud,longitud);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // enviarcoordenadasGET(Latitud,Longitud);
        Primeraubicacion = false;
    }
   YavieneFragment.this.setLocation(loc);
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es desactivado
    //       mensaje1.setText("GPS Desactivado");
    Log.e("ya viene","EL GPS ESTÁ DESACTIVADO");

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
    //         mensaje1.setText("GPS Activado");
    Log.e("ya viene","EL GPS ESTÁ ACTIVADO");

}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.e("ya viene","onStatusChanged");
    switch (status) {

        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
            break;
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
            break;
         }
         }
        }
            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            @Override
           public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
          ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
//CONSULTO SI LA APLICACIÓN TIENE ACCESO A LA UBICACIÓN DEL DISPOSITIVO MÓVIL, EN CASO DE NO TENERLO PIDO PERMISO PARA OBTENERLA
Log.e("ya viene","onCreateView");
             View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yaviene, container, false);
return v;
    }
           // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
         public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
         if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
        }
       @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
         }
         }
         @Override
         public void onDetach() {
         super.onDetach();
         mListener = null;
        }

        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
// TODO: Update argument type and name
void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
     }
```

Comment: ¿Tu problema es que no llama  Cargarwebview(0.0, 0.0); cuando se rechazan los permisos?

Comment: Exactamente, es como que solo funciona si el usuario presiona en aceptar los permisos.

Comment: Hola @Luis debes usar el callback onRequestPermissionsResult() , ahí puedes definir la lógica que deseas.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, ahora me surge otra duda. Por què el cartel de permisos me sale hasta que pongo aceptar? despues por mas que quite desde el cel la opcion de activar el gps nunca mas me tira el mensaje de permisos. Hay alguna especie de cache que guarda eso o cómo deberia hacer para que si o si me salté cada vez que ingresa a ese fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la logica que determina que cargar cuando se aceptan o no los permisos debe realizarse dentro de [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback) y no dentro de requestPermissions() como lo estas realizando.

Cambia tu código dentro de  [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback) :

```
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull
            String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        Log.i(TAG, "ingresa a RequestPermissionsResult requestCode: " +  requestCode + " grantResults[0]: "+ grantResults[0]);
        if (requestCode == 99) {

            if (grantResults[0] ==  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Permiso aceptado.
                locationStart();
                return;
            }else
            {
                //Permiso denegado.
                Cargarwebview(0.0, 0.0);              
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, ahora me surge otra duda. Por què el cartel de permisos me sale hasta que pongo aceptar? despues por mas que quite desde el cel la opcion de activar el gps nunca mas me tira el mensaje de permisos. Hay alguna especie de cache que guarda eso o cómo deberia hacer para que si o si me salté cada vez que ingresa a ese fragment

Comment: " Hay alguna especie de cache que guarda eso" si, no es necesario requerir el permiso cada vez que ingreses a tu aplicación. De hecho puedes entrar a la configuración de la aplicación si deseas desactivar el permiso y si entras nuevamente al detectar que no se tiene el permiso se mostraría el diálogo.

Comment: como haría lo de detectar cuando no tiene permiso y mostrar el dialogo nuevamente? porque el codigo digamos que hace "su magia" a partir de la ventana de dialogo sino no se ejecuta ni una ni otra. (avisame si debo abrir otra pergunta para esto por favor ya que me solucionaste la pregunta principal digamos)

Comment: "como haría lo de detectar cuando no tiene permiso y mostrar el dialogo nuevamente?" De hecho se realizaría automáticamente al iniciar tu aplicación ya que en onCreate() tienes el código para verificar el permiso "if (checkSelfPermission(getContext(),....".