# Localización Android con Kotlin - No responde lastLocation

Tags: android, kotlin

Soy nuevo en Kotlin y quisiera saber porque no estaría ingresando en la función .addOnSuccesListener para analizar el objeto location y sacar longitud y latitud.  Desde ya mil gracias x la ayuda!!

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var lastLocation: Location

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nueva)
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    getLastKnownLocation()
    }
fun getLastKnownLocation() {

    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener(this,  { location->
            if (location != null) {
                println("entro")

            }

        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

La declaración del listener es incorrecta, debe ser:

```
  fun getLastKnownLocation(){
        try {
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                    .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                        // Obtiene la úlmtima localización conocida.
                        if (location != null) {
                            lastLocation = location
                            val msg = "Updated Location: " +
                                    (location.latitude.toString()) + "," +
                                    (location.longitude.toString())
                            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            println("entro: " + msg)

                        }
                    }
        } catch(ex: SecurityException) {
            System.out.println("Security Exception, no location available" + ex.message)
        }

    }
```

Recuerda que es importante definir los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

y realizar su petición manual

[android studio, permisos de geolocalización](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274817/android-studio-permisos-de-geolocalizaci%c3%b3n)

Answer (score 0):

En el siguiente código si no hay una última ubicación conocida, solicita una nueva, sólo manda a llamar la función getlocation cuando lo necesites, espero te ayude

```
fun getLocation(){
    val mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        val location: Location? = task.result
        if (location == null) {
            requestNewLocationData()
        } else { 
          Log.d(TAG, "${location.latitude} ${location.longitude}")
        }
    }
}

private val mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
        val location: Location = locationResult.lastLocation

        Log.d(TAG, "${location.latitude} ${location.longitude}")
    }
}

private fun requestNewLocationData() {

    val mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()

    mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    mLocationRequest.interval = 0
    mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
    mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
        Looper.myLooper()!!
    )
}
```